# Angular: trigger change detection outside of angular dependency injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-changedetection

Is it possible to trigger angular change detection globally, without injecting something like ApplicationRef? I would want to use the following functionality as a plain js function and not as a service method. Thus avoiding to inject an extra service whereever the function is needed.

```js
export function frequentlyUsedUtilityFunction() {

  // ... do stuff

  // trigger change detection
  // get applicationRef or some similar mechanism
  const applicationRef = ...
  applicationRef.tick();

  // ... do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not shure what I fully understand your question, but maybe this way can help you:

1. Add code into AppComponent like this:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  fromEvent(document, 'myEventToCdrTrigger').subscribe(() => {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

2. From your custom function:

```
export function frequentlyUsedUtilityFunction() {
  const event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent('myEventToCdrTrigger', true, true);
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Your approach is a nice idea. It broght me to another idea. If you run a  `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)` in the utility function it should also trigger change detection (async action). However not tested.